# Crystal Reports Cross-Tab Column Totals as Variables

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I have a report within Crystal 2008 that has 2 subreports, each of which is a Crosstab. I have split them into different reports as their selection and database queries are unrelated.

What i need to be able to to is to create a variable for each of the Column Totals and be able to pass this onto a third report for each of the two cross Tabs.

The Layout of each cross tab is formatted the same, with the columns being the PO Number and the rows being charges against each PO. It is the total of the columns that I need to perform a further calculation on.

Total of Crosstab1 Column1 - Total of Crosstab2 Column1 for each column that is displayed by the selection query to give me a difference between the two crosstabs.

I have tried using the CurrentFieldValue but this only appears to set the total of the very last record to the variable.

I hope that there is a way to do this and that i have provided enough information for you to be able to assist me.

Comment: Actually a bit confused on your requirement. You want to subtract the column1 of crosstab1 and column1 of crosstab2 and display the result in 3rd report? Is this right or any other requirement.

Comment: Yes i have two seperate cross tabs on seperate sub reports and i want to subtract one column total from another. Pass the totals to named variables and have these displayed on main report footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its hard to get the value from crosstab but one workaround would be.

1. Create a shared variable in both subreports and assign the summary value to the shared variable.

Suppose cross tab is showing employee salary sum then in the formula assign the value to the shared variable as

```
Shared Numbervar report1;
report1:=Sum(employee.salary)
```

1. similarly do in the second subreport aswell.
2. Now in main report create a formula

   `Shared NumberVar report1;
   Shared NumberVar report2;
   report1+report2;`

let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks Siva, I can get it to take the last column total as a variable on both sub reports and then put these into a formula calculation using the CurrentFieldValue as a Display String on field in design. However i need to be able to take each column total as a different variable.

I fear that this may not be possible.

Comment: why are you going to **CurrentFieldValue** instead you can normally pass value from subreport to main report using shared variable.

Comment: I tried with CurrentFieldValue just to see if it would work. Do the column totals in a cross-tab have a function name that i can assign to a variable?

Comment: There won;t be any name as in crosstab it will sum automatically one workaround would be check the grouping the corsstab and implement the same formula... suppose if you viewing the employee salary sum then use the same in formula

Comment: Ok, thats what i thought. The only reason i am using a cross tab is simply as i could not figure out how to replicate what i want without a cross tab.

I can not figure out is there is a way to design a report to show the PO's from a range across the top and then associated charges with each PO down the side.

If there is a way to do this, it would remove the requirement for a Cross Tab completely.

Comment: if your requirement is getting columns **dynamically** then crosstab is the best option, If not just place the columns in the report side by side so that you can manuplate as you wish

Comment: np let me know if you need further assistance