# How to filter information within a Cross Tab in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, filter, crystal-reports, crosstab

I am trying to create a single cross tab that includes both filtered and non-filtered data. I understand that I could do this by creating separate cross tabs in separate groups, then using filter expert on the group level, but I need the results to displayed in the same cross tab. I believe a similar solution to this might work, but am unclear on the implementation:
[Crystal Reports Cross-Tab Column Totals as Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401979/crystal-reports-cross-tab-column-totals-as-variables)

I am attempting to report on the frequency of known customers and walk-in customers (given a set customer number).

I have created a report with a cross tab with the following values:

Rows: AR_CUST.STR_ID (gives store number)
Columns: PS_TKT_HIST_DAT (gives purchase date)

Summarized Fields:
DistinctCount of AR_CUST.CUST_NO (gives count of unique customer numbers)
DistinctCount of PS_TKT_HIST.TKT_NO (gives count of tickets)
Embedded Summary (gives ratio of unique customers to number of tickets)

This works exactly as it should.

We have one value of AR_CUST.CUST_NO that is used for walk-in customers (we don't retain customer information for purchases using this customer number). So I want to calculate two additional cross tabs with the same information. The first would exclude all entries in PS_TKT_HIST.TKT_NO when PS_TKT_HIST.CUST_NO equals *WI (that's not a wildcard, that's the exact entry in SQL). The second wouldn't exclude *WI records, but would count each instance of a ticket under the *WI customer number as a separate customer.  To clarify that, in the second report, my embedded summary in the cross tab would be:

DISTINCT_COUNT of CUST_NO when CUST_NO <> *WI +
COUNT of CUST_NO when CUST_NO = *WI

Is this possible by recording embedded summary values from the three cross tabs as variables, and then inserting those variables into a fourth crosstab?

Thanks

Tyler

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can extract the embeeded summary from 3 cross tabs and insert in 4th cross tab. `May be I don't know`.....

But I can suggest you one work around for this.

Since you have 3 cross tabs...

1. Take 3 sub reports in the main report and implement the individual cross tab in the 3 sub reports..
2. Implement the cross tab not by using the cross tab but by placing the recurring fields in the detail section and summary in the footer section and divide the detail sections using lines.. and make the report as exactly as cross tab.

   ```
        Row    Column1 | Column2 | Column3   //Group Header as cross tab columns
       -------------------------------------
        1       10     |     10   |  10     //Detail Section as cross tab rows
        2       20     |     20   |  20     //Detail section as cross tab rows
       --------------------------------------  // Lines will be line objects in crosstab
                30     |     30   |  30     //Group Footer as cross tab summary
   ```

   Above design will give your out exactly as corss tab.
3. Now from 3 sub reports take the required values using the `Shared Varialbes` and perform your calcultion in main subreport or another sub report as per your requirement.

For eg in subreport create like this:

```
Shared NumberVar x;

X:=DISTINCT_COUNT of CUST_NO when CUST_NO <> *WI +
COUNT of CUST_NO when CUST_NO = *WI
```

In main report

```
Shared NumberVar x;
x
```

Perform same in all sub reports.

This approach will give you cross tab output at the same time you can manuplate the calculations.

Let me know how it goes