# Sub Report /Main report cross tab fields difference,

Tags: crosstab, crystal-reports-2010

I have a main report with a cross tab that shows Income of  `regions`
Similarly a sub report is called in the main report that shows `Expense` of the same regions

Now I have to show the Deficit/surplus b/w the income and expense of each region.

How do I go about it? Any suggestions? I am trying `shared variable` but that just gives me the `total difference between the two reports.`

```
----------
     Income              Expense           Surplus/Def 

 - Region1--  1000         Region1 -- 500    --  500
 - Region2 -- 2000         Region2--  2000   --  0
 - Region3--  3000         Region3 -- 2000    -- 1000
 - Total  --  6000         Total ---   4500    - 1500
```

p.s I can't seem to indent my columns for ease of reading above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to manuplate these kind of calculations in cross tab.. but one way around would be.

Approach 1:

1. As I see your cross tabs are simple hence instead of sub report use both corss tabs in main report it self.
2. For difference (Surpless or deficit) use 3rd cross tab and create the same hierarchy as of the first two and write `difference` formula.

Approach 2:

See the post below where I gave the answer to get the cross tab functionality without using the cross tab. Check the `answer` part in below link

[How to filter information within a Cross Tab in Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065451/how-to-filter-information-within-a-cross-tab-in-crystal-reports/23075935#23075935)

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you! Trying the approaches . Will update soon.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Converted cross tabs into a case query. Finding the difference between the group (income and expense) using separate variables, for each region . Is there any other way to calc differences within a group? I can see various summation options but not difference.

Comment: can you elaborate `with in group`?

Comment: My grouping is based on "natureofaccount" i.e income or expense. So i get a subtotal for each region after income and similar total after expenses. I want deficit/surplus between the two. Currently i am using a varaible with diff formula in group footer but adding it for 23 regions seems cumbersome and not right.

Comment: one option will be using sub reports.. 1st sub report for Income and second for expences and difference in main report